# ggplot omits polygon holes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having difficulty getting ggplot to plot polygons that feature holes. The following demonstrates.  First get the shapefile with `git clone https://github.com/geotheory/volcano`.  Next:

```
require(ggplot2); require(ggmap); require(dplyr); require(maptools)
v = readShapePoly('volcano/volcano.shp')
v@proj4string = CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')

# confirm polygons spatially exclusive (don't overlap)
plot(t(bbox(v)), type='l', lwd=8)
plot(v, col=paste0(colorRampPalette(c('grey','red'))(8),'dd'), add=T)
```

[image]

Looks ok. A `dd` alpha should render the line invisible if obscured by multiple polygons.  Now let's try in ggplot.

```
d = fortify(v) %>% as_data_frame()
bb = bbox(v)
toner = get_stamenmap(c(bb[1,1], bb[2,1], bb[1,2], bb[2,2]), zoom=11, maptype='toner')
ggmap(toner) + geom_polygon(data=d, aes(long, lat, group=group, fill=id), alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Central polygons must be overlapping since the underlying map is completely obscured in the centre. Let's check the fortified data for holes:

```
d %>% select(id, hole) %>% table()
   hole
id  FALSE TRUE
  0   278    0
  1   715    0
  2   392  388
  3   388  331
  4   390  265
  5   265  387
  6   328  125
  7   125    0
```

Looks ok, so let's try visualising them individually.

```
i = 3
plot(v[i,], col='red') 
ggplot(filter(d, id == i-1)) + geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group=group, col=hole), fill=NA)
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=filter(d, id==i-1), aes(long,lat, group=group))
```

[image]

Something appears to be going wrong. ggplot seems to be ignoring the holes. Unless it's a problem with the shapefile. Any suggestions how to diagnose/fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["hadley/ggplot2: plotting polygon shapefiles"](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) says *"..., the hole state is retained, but this information is not used by ggplot2"*. Fortunately, `ggspatial` package, ["Fish & Whistle: Holes in ggplot polygons"](http://apps.fishandwhistle.net/archives/1126) taught me, seem to solve some problems, such as the overlapping problem. (The white area upper the label of "Biggin Hill" isn't due to `ggspatial` package because it is also on `ggplot(d) + geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = id))` on my env)

```
devtools::install_github("paleolimbot/ggspatial")

library(ggspatial)

ggmap(toner) + geom_spatial(data=v, aes(fill=id), alpha=.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on world map with the country Lesotho. Normally, ggplot2 should detect hole, because the sens of the polygone is reverse (anticlokwise instead of clockwise if I remember).

Here the solution seems to drop the hole from the selection.

```
colorsbrewer_red <-  c( "#fff5f0","#fee0d2", "#fcbba1","#fc9272", "#fb6a4a", "#ef3b2c", "#cb181d",  "#99000d")

ggmap(toner) +  
geom_polygon(data=d[!d$hole,], aes(long, lat, group=group, fill=id), alpha=.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                    values= colorsbrewer_red,
                    na.value = "# 808080",
                    drop=FALSE)
```

[image: volcano_in_london]

Anyway, if someone know how to deal directly with hole in `geom_polygon`, It would be great.

Comment: Thanks @timat. Still a problem for me as I need the holes otherwise the polys overlap and the underlying map is obscured..